# Get data of relation from Query function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Hi everyone i need to get tag name in relation tasktags using query but I get an error

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$name

```
$posts2 = Path::with(['pathtags' => function ($q) use ($TagArray) {
    $q->with(['Tasks'=>function($q) use ($TagArray) { 
        $q->has('tasktags', '=' , 2)
        ->whereHas('tasktags', function ($query) use ($TagArray) {
            $TaskTags[] = $query->name;
       })->with('tasktags');
    }]);
}])->first();
```

Comment: `$query->name` is the error here. Because `$query` is a `QueryBuilder` instance. just specify what are you trying to do here. so we can provide a correct approach.

Comment: 'm trying to get tasktags name into array

Comment: `$pathTags = Path::first()->pathtags->map->name;` isn't this what you are looking for?

Comment: No, I need it so i can use  it i query function so i can return tasks where thir tasktasg  is in $TagArray

Comment: need it to be in query function

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I think you want here:

```
$posts2 = Path::with(['pathtags' => function ($q) use ($TagArray) {
    $q->with(['Tasks'=>function($q) use ($TagArray) { 
        $q->has('tasktags', '=' , 2)
        ->whereHas('tasktags', function ($query) use ($TagArray) {
            $q->whereIn('name', $TagArray);
       })->with('tasktags');
    }]);
}])->first();
```

so you choose only paths that has tasktags with given names.

Comment: yes this is the first step but the problem is i want return tasks where all tasktags name is  in the array but whereIn return when one of tasktags name is in the array

Comment: i tried to add all tasktags name in array to check if all tasktags anme array is in $TagArray